# The default DbConfiguration instance was used by the Entity Framework before an attempt was made to set an instance

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm receiving this exception (see below) when using EF6, most likely because there is already in same AppDomain a custom DbConfiguration with slightly different parameters (however still for SQLite).

- I'm not able to change app.config (therefore I'm creating my own DbConfiguration associated to my DbContext class).
- I'm also not able to change the 3 rd party code which already invoked DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration (.,.).
- I already tried to provide DbConfigurationType with type of 'SqliteConfiguration' on my DbContext (but still same exception).

Exception
InvalidOperationException: The default DbConfiguration instance was used by the Entity Framework before an attempt was made to set an instance of 'SqliteConfiguration'. The 'SqliteConfiguration' instance must be set at application start before using any Entity Framework features or must be registered in the application's config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260883 for more information.

My question would be:

- Should I create secondary AppDomain where I create\manipulate my DbDontext ? (with wrapping layer (e.g. for CRUD operations).
- In case yes, is there any known performance drawback ?
- Is there any other solution assuming that I can't change 3rd party code ?